# Is there a way to split a string separated by lines, into a 2D Array?

Tags: javascript, string, multidimensional-array, split

I am a beginner to javascript and I am confused on how to split a string which is separated by line breaks, into a 2d array. Here is the string. The numbers represent something that I need to make the code function, so excuse that:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
20000000010000000000000100000001000001000001000000000001000000000100010000010000010000000100001
11011111110111111111110101110101011101011101011101111101111111010101011101010101110101111100101
11000000010000010001010001000100010001000100000101000100000100010101000101010100000100000000101
11011111011111010101011111011111011111011111111101010111110101110101110101110111111111111111101
11010001000001000101000001010001010000010000010001010001000101010100010001000100010001000100001
11010101111101111101110101010101010111110111010111011101011101010111011111011101010101011100101
11010100000000000100010101000100010000010001000101010001000001010100010001010001000100010000101
11010111111111110111010101111111011111011101111101010111111111010101010101010101111111110111101
11010100000000000001010100000001000001000100010000010000010000000001010100010101000000000100001
11010111011111111101010111011111110111110111011111011111010111111111010111110111011111111111111
11010001000100010001010101010000010100010001000001010001000101000001010000000100010000000000001
11011101110101010111010101010101010101010111111101011101111101011101110111111101110111111111101
11000101000101010001010001000101010001000100000001000001000001010100000100000001000100000100001
11011101111101011111011111111101111111111101111111111101110101010111111101111101011101110101111
11010001000001010000010000000100000100000001000001000100000101010000000100010001000101000100001
11010111011111010111110111110111110101111111010111010111111101010111110111011111110111011111001
11010001010001000100000100000000000101000000010001010001000001000101000101000100010001000100001
11011101011101111111110111111111110101011111111101011101011111111101011101110101011101110101001
11010101000100000000010000000100000101000000000101000100000000010001000100010001000000000101001
11010101110101111111011111110111111101111111111101110101111101110101110111011111111111111101001
11000100010100010001000000000100000001000000000100010101000101000101000100010100000001000001001
11110101110100010111111111011101111111011111110101110101010111011101011101010101011101011111111
11000101000100010100000001010001000000010001000101000101010000000100000001010001000101000000001
11011101011101110101011111010111011111110111011101011101011111111111111111010111110111111111001
11000100010001000101000001010001000000010100010100000001010001000001000001010100000100010001001
11110111110101110101111101011101111111010101110101111111010111011101010111010101110101010101001
11000100010100010100010101000100000001000101000001010001000100010101010001010100010101010100001
11011101010111010111010101110111111101110101111101010101011101110101111101011111010101010111111
11000101000100010000010100000000000100000100000100010100010001010001000100000000010101010000001
11110101111101011111010111111111111111111101110111010111110111010111010111111111110101011111001
11010100010001010001000001010000000001000100010100010001010100010100010000000000010101000000001
11010111010111110101111101010101111101010111110101111101010101110101011111111111011101111111001
11000100010100000101000000010101000100010000010100010000010101000101000001000001000100010001001
11011111110101111111011111110111010111111111010111110111110101011111111101011101110101010101001
11000000000100010000000100010000010100010001010000000100000101000000010001000100000101000101001
11111111110111011111011101010111110101010101011111110101111101111111010111111111011111011101001
11000000000101000001010001010100000101010100010000010100010001000000010000000001010001010001001
11011111111101111101110111011101111101010111110111011111010111011111111111111101010101110111001
11000000000000000100000100000001000001000000000100000000010000000000000000000001000100000100003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey buddy I'm also new but I actually have an idea. You can try this:
`a.split("\n");`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I cannot believe how simple it was.